# How does "importaddress" command in bitcoin-cli work?

Tags: importaddress

I am trying to use "importaddress" in regtest mode. I have two bitcoin-core nodes running.  I generated address on one node, imported it on another node and then sent some coins to this address. If I run "listreceivedbyaddress 0 true" on the first node, I see right amount of coins on this adddress and right txid. If I run "listreceivedbyaddress 0 true" on the second node, I see zero amount of coins on this adddress and no txid.

Comment: Did you rescan after importing the address?

Comment: Yes, I did rescan after importing the address.

Comment: Are you sure the two regtest nodes are actually connected to each other?

Comment: Yes, I am sure. When I send coins from wallet on one node to wallet on another node I can see this transaction in "listtransactions" output on both.

Comment: What if you generate a block and confirm the TX?

Comment: Ok. You could check the logs on both nodes as well maybe there is a reason the unconfirmed tx wasn't accepted in the mempool of node 2, for example